# Type refinements on an object in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I'm having trouble understanding why [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCgpQD5QN4F8Ns8AbCAZ3IHsA7cgLjwHMAnKgVzAahvYFsARhBb5CaAGbsaAY2ABLWlHFUqACnIIkjOIggBKPETnioqgIQbdAOjKVa5AywjB2LGlAAsAJiJOXbqEskGwpqOitWDi40QiA) complains. Give the discussion of [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) in the docs, I would expect the exact object type to fix the problem. Can anyone point to my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my example was wrong. [Here's](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCgpQD5QN5awF8Ns8AbCAZ0oHsA7SgLjygHMAnGgVzCajq4BbAEYR2UQsTShIUAOIRgcRCigAKAJRRkAPlgIkaNAHpjUACI0qdAOTAoAdxrsA1gBooogMbwulaACSNoJsisAAlnSsUPBQAGbsVAAWUJQG0BAAbmIgUBGC0PB0ACb8NPaJcZGR0cBJ0DTCAFYQXsAAdGhxXHRt4fTxNDRqrIrKSMwKSulauCThceoAhKPTKprtFNT0lFqJwFzsdFAALABMJPuHx6vjEBtbtAztHNy8aFKmFlaUjs7unlavn8UCCIUq1SieXqUEaLTa0PCv3yEC6PT6A2E8HYIzG6UmeJUsxIXh29jSKm0oTWSE080WaiWFKQmyoT12UCuR1OF0wXOOzIgrO2z1ePEoHyAA) what was actually going on, it had to do with refining the result of a function each time vs. storing the result of the function and refining that.